# Add a document to IBM Watson Discovery with php CURL

Tags: php, ibm-watson

I've been trying without success to add a document to a collection using the Watson Discovery API using PHP CURL. This is what I've got so far:

```
    $doc = 'documents/comment_' . $id . '.json';
    $fields = [
        'file' => new \CURLFile($doc, 'application/json', 'comment_' . $id)
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $method);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:' . $apikey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
```

I realise that this is probably not correct, but I have tried all sorts of combinations and I'm not getting any result - i.e. no error messages, nothing.
Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

PHP 7.0 (Laravel)

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` show? How about [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)?

Comment: @ceejayoz - not getting anything from either

Answer (score 0):

try something alike this, to at least get some information "why":

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if($response == false){
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
}
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

also, installing [xDebug](https://xdebug.org) might help a lot there.